# How do you populate boolean columns based on a table of properties?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have a table called Product that contains a product identification number and an id associated with the product identification number.

```
pin id
11 10
12 11
13 12
```

I also have a property table with the id and property_id

```
id property_id
10, 108
11, 109
12, 200
```

108 refers to the property isNew, 109 refers to the property isPremium and 200 refers to the property isExclusive.

With these, I want to create this temporary table:

```
pin id isNew isPremium isExclusive
11 10 1 0 0
12 11 0 1 0
13 12 0 0 1
```

How do I do this? You can create a temporary table easily, but I am not sure how to map the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select pt.pin, pt.id,
    max(case when py.property_id = 108 then 1 else 0 end) as is_new,
    max(case when py.property_id = 109 then 1 else 0 end) as is_premium,
    max(case when py.property_id = 200 then 1 else 0 end) as is_exclusive
from product pt
inner join property py on py.id = pt.id
group by pt.pin, pt.id
```

This assumes that there may be several properties per product - unlike what is showed in your sample data. If that's not the case, aggregation is not necessary:

```
select pt.pin, pt.id,
    case when py.property_id = 108 then 1 else 0 end as is_new,
    case when py.property_id = 109 then 1 else 0 end as is_premium,
    case when py.property_id = 200 then 1 else 0 end as is_exclusive
from product pt
inner join property py on py.id = pt.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PIVOT function to get the result you want.

```sql
DECLARE @product table(pin int, id int)
DECLARE @property table(id int, property_id int)

insert into @product
values 
(11 ,10),
(12 ,11),
(13 ,12);

insert into @property
values
(10, 108),
(11, 109),
(12, 200);

SELECT pvt.pin, pvt.product_id, [108] as is_new,[109] as is_premium, [200] as is_exclusive  
FROM 
(SELECT p.pin, p.id, pr.id as product_id, pr.property_id
FROM @Product as p
INNER JOIN @Property as pr
ON pr.id = p.id) as t
PIVOT
(
COUNT(t.id)
for t.Property_Id in ([108],[109],[200])
) as pvt
```

```
+-----+------------+--------+------------+--------------+
| pin | product_id | is_new | is_premium | is_exclusive |
+-----+------------+--------+------------+--------------+
|  11 |         10 |      1 |          0 |            0 |
|  12 |         11 |      0 |          1 |            0 |
|  13 |         12 |      0 |          0 |            1 |
+-----+------------+--------+------------+--------------+
```